# Как через ssh запустить загрузку через curl и оставить, закрыв при этом ssh-сессию?

Tags: curl, ssh, download

Хочу через curl скачать большой объём данных, делегировав эту задачу RaspberryPI, доступ к которой есть только по SSH. После закрытия SSH-сессии загрузка прерывается. Как запустить загрузку и закрыть терминал так, чтобы "малина" продолжала качать?

Comment: nohup    https://linuxhandbook.com/nohup-command/   https://askubuntu.com/questions/349262/run-a-nohup-command-over-ssh-then-disconnect

Comment: `tmux`/`screen`. https://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session